# Incorrect font locking/syntax hightlighting in c-mode

Tags: font-lock, c-mode

I've recently started using Emacs, and I'm having a problem with the font-locking in `c-mode`.
I'm using the Monokai theme, and I'm finding that some tokens are being coloured incorrectly.

[image: fontlocking]

The problem is that built in functions (`strlen`, `malloc`, `strcpy`) aren't being recognised and highlighted in the correct colour.

It also seems to think that the `n` in the call to `malloc` in the second function is a type.

I'm not really sure where to turn with this, so I'd appreciate any help in sorting this out.

Comment: The variable `n` misrecognized as a  type really bugs me.